# Xcode Editor text selection issue

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, textselection

If I want to delete few lines of text in most of text editors, not touching some words on the bottom line and the whole upper line, I put cursor on the bottom row leaving all unnecessary words to the left of the cursor. Then  I select few lines vertically by holding <kbd>Shift + ↑</kbd>. I stop on upper row and get some selection: part below + right part of the upper row:

[image: Selected rows]

In this example I want to get rid of `if` word and an empty space between the function header and the code, not touching the function header *(even hough `let` will stick to the opening bracket `{`)*.
Normally *(not in Xcode)* I would still hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and will press <kbd>cmd + ➝</kbd> to deselect the right *(selected)* part or the top row.
Result will be like this:

[image: Good shortcut row selection]

I can simply press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and job is done.

However, in Xcode such shortcut usage makes bottom row fully selected (till the right) and not changes upper row selection:

[image: Wrong Xcode selection]

Same thing happens if you select from top to bottom and you need to remove extra selection from the bottom line.

I tried to rebind shortcuts in **Preferences** but didn't find a solution.
This example is very particular and maybe not the best, however ***I face such selection problems only in Xcode*** and have to use mouse which is not handy.

Comment: I have the same question. I seems small but I am so used to this with other editors that it is frustrating Xcode does not work the same.

Comment: Xcode is completely broken when it comes to text selection and no one seems to care, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question, but what you want is fairly simple to achieve. If your cursor is between the `if` and the `let`, you would only need to press option-shift-left arrow twice. The first time, it would select the if and the leading tabs, and the second would select the empty line.